# Assign Octave matrix elements to variables

Tags: variables, matrix, octave

I am trying to do something like this in Octave:

Assign some variables to a matrix, do some operation on the matrix and then assign the members of the matrix back to the variables, e.g:

```
x=1; y=2; d=[x y];
d=(d.^2)+1;
[x y]=d;
```

However, this does not work and only x is assigned the complete matrix. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can index into `d`.

```
x=d(1);   y=d(2);
```

or convert `d` to a cell array using [`num2cell`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/num2cell.html) and then to a [comma-separated list](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Comma-Separated-Lists.html) and then [`deal`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/deal.html) it.

```
[x, y] = deal(num2cell(d){:});
```

I recommend the first method.

Comment: The second way is what I was looking for (although I don't completely understand it). Thank you!

Comment: One-liners are overrated. Anyway, try doing it in parts and see the output for each part. Let me know if you still find anything unclear